# using for loop to add values to a MySQL Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql

***PHP:***

```
$bookquery = "SELECT * FROM heli_book ORDER BY book_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$bookget = mysql_query("$bookquery");
$booking = mysql_fetch_assoc($bookget, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$custquery = "SELECT cust_id FROM heli_cust LIMIT ".$total."";
$custget = mysql_query("$custquery");
$cust = mysql_fetch_assoc($custget, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$bcusquery = "INSERT INTO heli_bcus (bcus_book, bcus_cust) VALUES ";

for($x = 0; $x < count($cust_fname); $x++) {
    $bcusquery .= "('".$bookid."', '".$custid."')";
    if ($x+1 != $total) {
        $bcusquery .= ", ";
    }
} 

        echo "<br>";
        echo $bcusquery;
```

I am trying to get `$custid` to seqence through the array, but it keeps coming up as the first item in the array.

***Current Result:***
('01', 'A'), ('01', 'A'), ('01', 'A')

***Desired Result:***
('01', 'A'), ('01', 'B'), ('01', 'C')

`$total` is the value of `count(array_filter($cust_fname))`
`$cust_fname = array_filter($_POST[cust_fname]);`

Comment: So we have desired result. And what is current result?

Comment: Just a side note, before someone else shoots you: you should NOT use the mysql_* prototype since it is deprecated (from quite a while), you should use either mysqli_* or PDO instead, regardless the type of query you're doing.

Comment: editted above @u_mulder

Comment: thanks @briosheje people have discussed this with me, but my entire site is written is mysql_*, so it is easier to work with the old for now..

Comment: And what is `cust_name`? Where is it defined?

Comment: amended aswell @u_mulder

Comment: @JamesHam: It's totally Okay to me, I just want to be sure that you're aware that it is NOT safe anymore to use mysql_* for actually a lot of reasons BUT, if you're aware of that, it's totally okay :P

Comment: where is $cust_fname anyway?

Comment: @briosheje - at the very bottom

"`$cust_fname = array_filter($_POST[cust_fname]);`"

Comment: Oh okay, at this point, however, I'm confused.. Where are you getting the $custid from? It seems to be the problem, but I'm not sure if you're extracting in some strange way from an array or whatever :P

Comment: @briosheje `$custid = $cust[cust_id];`  `$bookid = $booking[book_id];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

To do so - move the `$booking = mysql_fetch_assoc($bookget, MYSQL_ASSOC);` into the `for` loop!

***ie:***

```
        $bookquery = "SELECT * FROM heli_book ORDER BY book_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $bookget = mysql_query("$bookquery");
        $booking = mysql_fetch_assoc($bookget, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        $custquery = "SELECT cust_id FROM heli_cust LIMIT ".$total."";
        $custget = mysql_query("$custquery");


        $bcusquery = "INSERT INTO heli_bcus (bcus_book, bcus_cust) VALUES ";

        $custid = $cust[cust_id];
        $bookid = $booking[book_id];

for($x = 0; $x < count($cust_fname); $x++) {
    $cust = mysql_fetch_assoc($custget, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $bcusquery .= "('".$bookid."', '".$cust[cust_id]."')";
    if ($x+1 != $total) {
        $bcusquery .= ", ";
    }
} 

        echo "<br>";
        echo $bcusquery;
```